# Using 'array.each { |x| puts x }' to draw a bar graph made from multiple "-", throws a TypeError

Tags: ruby, each, typeerror

```
graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * x}
```

graph_nums is an array of numbers, and I'm trying to represent each number as multiples of "-", e.g. 3 would be "---".

```
i = 3
graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * i}
```

and

```
graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * 3}
```

Both behave as expected. And

```
graph_nums.each {|x| puts x}
```

Returns the numbers, but combining these ideas throws an error.

```
graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * graph_nums[0]}
```

or

```
graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * x}
```

`*': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

For an array of numbers 1-6, I'd expect to see

```
-
--
---
----
-----
------
```

Why does one or the other work, but not both? Is there a solution using this format, or do I need to go the long way round?

Comment: Seems to be related to `graph_nums`, why don't you show how you set / assign it?

Comment: I should have, the array was made using gets, so the numbers were strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you posted works:

```
[4] pry(main)> graph_nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[5] pry(main)> graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * x}
-
--
---
----
-----
------
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Most probably `graph_nums` is an array of strings. You can convert them to integers using `String#to_i`:

```
[6] pry(main)> graph_nums = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
[7] pry(main)> graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * x}
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
from (pry):7:in `*'
[8] pry(main)> graph_nums.each {|x| puts "-" * x.to_i}
-
--
---
----
-----
------
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

Comment: That's done it. The array was made using gets, does that always result in strings?

Comment: Yes, `gets` gives you a string